# Is there any directly queriable "knowledge graph"?

Tags: database, graph

I'm talking about the knowledge graph concept google has recently incorporated to google search. But my question is wheter there is a knowledge graph that I can directly query via API or a client. For illustration, see this specific query:

```
search for "books" which contain the word "apple" and are linked to the "second war"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at http://www.freebase.com. It's a queriable entiry graph with a web API. I think it's the biggest free knowledge base of this kind.

Comment: Not the same thing, as this is user submitted as oposed to data-minned. It is probably the best we have available for the public.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try http://unigraph.rocks - a large and open KG.

The sandbox is available at http://u01.unigraph.rocks and the documentation is here: https://github.com/unigraph/docs/wiki

Comment: should be a comment.